# Jest with angular unable to turn on coverage because of es6

Tags: javascript, angular, jestjs, code-coverage, es6-modules

I'm trying to set up an angular project to work with jest. So far it works with the following config

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  // other stuff
  preset: "jest-preset-angular",
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts"],
  globalSetup: "jest-preset-angular/global-setup",
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      tsconfig: "<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json",
      stringifyContentPathRegex: "\\.html$",
      useESM: true,
    },
  },
};
```

And the following in my `setup-jest.ts`

```
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
import './jest-global-mocks';
```

Problem is that as soon as I introduce any code that brings in an ES module, it blows up (even though I've tried following the [ESM support page](https://thymikee.github.io/jest-preset-angular/docs/guides/esm-support) on the `jest-preset-angular` docs). So far, I've just dealt with this by finding alternative packages. But when I try to turn on `--coverage`, I get this.

```
 import { __decorate } from "tslib";
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
    > 2 | import { AppModule } from './app.module';
        | ^
      3 | import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
      4 |
      5 | describe('The app module', () => {
```

I've tried dissecting `jest-preset-angular` and extracting the settings that seem like they should apply to projects using ES6, which has led me to making these changes:

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  // other stuff
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts"],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/(?!tslib)"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|html|svg)$": "jest-preset-angular",
  },
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: [".ts"],
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      tsconfig: "<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json",
      stringifyContentPathRegex: "\\.html$",
      useESM: true,
    },
  },
};
```

And now its failing on the core angular `mjs` files

```
/Users/benwainwright1/repos/ng-budget/node_modules/@testing-library/angular/fesm2020/testing-library-angular.mjs:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import * as i0 from '@angular/core';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

This is even more confusing for me because as far as I can see

- the `transform` key doesn't specify `.mjs`, so `.mjs` files should be left alone
- I'm using node v16 and jest v28, which should automatically treat `.mjs` files as modules